# Does Yoshi B-type have an ending?

Tags: yoshi

Does the NES version of [*Yoshi*](http://www.nindb.net/game/yoshi.html) (a.k.a. *Yoshi's Egg*, *Mario & Yoshi*) have an ending when playing the B-type game, or does the game just keep getting faster?

If there is not an ending, how many different fruits are there on the interstitials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mushroom
2. Fire Flower
3. Piranha Plant
4. Shell
5. Star
6. Apple
7. Apple
8. Strawberry
9. Strawberry
10. Melon
11. Melon
12. Plum?
13. Plum?
14. Grapes
15. Grapes
16. Pineapple

I've seen pineapple repeat three times times, so I'm going to assume that's the last fruit, and there is no end.

Answer (score 5):

1. Mushroom
2. Fire Flower
3. Piranha Plant
4. Shell
5. Star
6. Apple
7. Apple
8. Strawberry
9. Strawberry
10. Melon
11. Melon
12. Plum
13. Plum
14. Grapes
15. Grapes
16. Pineapple
17. Pineapple
18. Pineapple
19. Cherries
20. Cherries
21. Cherries
22. Gold key

I did not make it past level 22.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just add this to the other answer in an edit?

Comment: @Vemonus - Our current stance on the matter is if you have new information, [post it as a new answer, don't edit it into the original](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7575/28182). There's an edit  rejection reason for that: *"This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."*

Comment: Only thing I would add - Justin should still list the other 16 steps as well, given our latest discussion on [Duplicate answers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4972/28182), one of the points raised is that 'duplicates' need to substantially improve upon the previous post or add additional information to stick around. Listing all the awards *plus* the new information would be a good answer - especially given the original answer incorrectly states "I'm going to assume that's the last fruit".